# Is it possible to make 1 pc camera work at 2 different modes simultaneously？

Tags: language-agnostic, camera, driver

By **mode** here I mean video `width`,`height` and `FPS`(frame per second)

I guess maybe some kinda driver can manage to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean hardwarewise, i highly doubt it.

When you just mean two different outputstreams... thats not that big of a deal and definitely possible.

Comment: I mean hardwarewise. or `virtual hardware`, to be exact.

Comment: Then it would depend on the camera used and the wrapping through the virtual system. 

Depending on the system i could think of some ways to implement such behaviour. For instance one output might be the original feed and the other one would be scaled to another proportion apropriate for your intended use.